# When does the memory transfer from CPU to GPU happen when creating a buffer?

Tags: directx, directx11, memory

I just finished my first DirectX 11 program. But I have several questions on memory transfer between CPU and GPU.

In my program, I create a vertex buffer first:

```
bool InitializeGeometry() {
    VertexType vertices[] = {
        XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f),
        XMFLOAT3(0.5f, 0.0f, 0.5f),
        XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f)
    };

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC vbDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&vbDesc, sizeof(vbDesc));
    vbDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE;
    vbDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(vertices);
    vbDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    vbDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA vbData;
    ZeroMemory(&vbData, sizeof(vbData));
    vbData.pSysMem = vertices;

    if (FAILED(gDevice->CreateBuffer(&vbDesc, &vbData, &gVB)))
        return false;

    // ...
}
```

Later I will use this vertex buffer for rendering.
Note that the `vertices` array is a stack variable and it will be destroyed on after the return of `InitializeGeometry`.

Does actual memory transfer from CPU to GPU happen in `CreateBuffer`?
Or `CreateBuffer` just takes a reference to the `vertices` so I should give a longer lifetime to the `vertices`?

If the transfer does *starts* in `CreateBuffer`(or `Unmap` for dynamic buffers),
can I expect the GPU driver save a copy of my vertices?
I am afraid that the transfer takes so much time that `InitializeGeometry` function returns early, hence leaves transferring data incomplete.

Comment: It is certainly safe to discard the buffer after the API call returns. I can't say this with certainty, but I assume the user has no control over when the driver will actually transfer data to the device. More than likely it will keep system memory copies of your data, in a any case.

Comment: @glampert Yes, I agree with you that the user has no control over when the driver will actually transfer data to the device. But I think knowing the mechanism helps me to decide the lifetime of my data in the CPU side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the functions that take a lump of data like `CreateBuffer`, `CreateVertexShader` and others, they copy/interpret the data before the function returns.

As soon as it returns, you do not need to keep the data alive anymore.